# Terraform does not deploy correct resources

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

I'm new to Terraform and unable to deploy the below and banging my head against it. The Terraform is unable to deploy the correct resources to my environment and unsure of what I've missed. Any help is appreciated. Code is below.

Thanks (Any advice in general on Terraform is appreciated. I can tell its going to be something very obvious but a one hour exercise has been bothering me all day!)

```
provider "aws" {
region="us-east-1"
}

data "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
    tags = {
    Name = "vpc"
    }
}

data "aws_subnet_ids" "ecommerce" {
    vpc_id = "${data.aws_vpc.vpc.id}"

    tags = {
    Name = "database"
    }
}

resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "aurora" {
    name       = "aurora"
    subnet_ids = ["${data.aws_subnet_ids.ecommerce.ids}"]

    tags = {
    Name = "database"
    }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "database" {
    name        = "database"
    description = "ecommerce database"
    vpc_id      = "${data.aws_vpc.vpc.id}"
    
    tags = {
    Name = "database"
    }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "web" {
    name        = "web"
    description = "ecommerce web"
    vpc_id      = "${data.aws_vpc.vpc.id}"

    tags = {
    Name = "web"
    }
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "web_allow_https_in" {
    description       = "HTTPS access"
    type              = "ingress"
    from_port         = 443
    to_port=443
    protocol          = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks       = ["8.8.8.8/32"]
    security_group_id = "${aws_security_group.web.id}"
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "web_allow_mysql_out" {
    description              = "MySQL access"
    type                     = "egress"
    from_port= 3306
    to_port                  = 3306
    protocol                 = "tcp"
    security_group_id        = "${aws_security_group.web.id}"
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "db_allow_web_in" {
    description              = "Web access"
    type                     = "ingress"
    from_port                = 3306
    to_port                  = 3306
    protocol="tcp"
    security_group_id        = "${aws_security_group.database.id}"
    source_security_group_id = "${aws_security_group.web.id}"
}

data "aws_ami" "web" {
    owners      = ["self"]
    most_recent = true

    filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["web*"]
    }
}

resource "aws_instance" "web" {
    ami                         = "${data.aws_ami.web.id}"
    ebs_optimized               = true
    instance_type               = "t3.micro"
    associate_public_ip_address = false
    vpc_security_group_ids      = ["${aws_security_group.web.id}"]
    subnet_id                   = "${data.aws_subnet_ids.ecommerce.ids[0]}"

    ebs_block_device = {
    device_name           = "/dev/sdb"
    volume_type           = "gp2"
    volume_size           = "16"
    delete_on_termination = true
    }

    tags = {
    Name  = "Web"
    }

    lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = ["ami"]
    }
}

resource "aws_rds_cluster" "aurora" {
    apply_immediately         = true
    backup_retention_period   = 7
    cluster_identifier        = "mydatabase"
    engine                    = "aurora"
    database_name             = "main"
    storage_encrypted=true
    kms_key_id = "arn:aws**"
    db_subnet_group_name      = "${aws_db_subnet_group.aurora.id}"
    final_snapshot_identifier = "final"
    master_password           = "*"
    master_username           = "*"
    vpc_security_group_ids    = ["${aws_security_group.database.id}"]
}

resource "aws_rds_cluster_instance" "aurora" {
    count = 2

    apply_immediately    = true
    identifier           = "mydatabase-${count.index}"
    cluster_identifier   = "${aws_rds_cluster.aurora.id}"
    db_subnet_group_name = "${aws_db_subnet_group.aurora.id}"
    instance_class       = "db.r12.large"
    publicly_accessible  = false
}

resource "aws_eip" "eip" {
    vpc = true
}

resource "aws_eip_association" "assoc" {
    instance_id   = "${aws_instance.web.id}"
    allocation_id = "${aws_eip.eip.id}"
}

data "aws_route53_zone" "zone" {
    name     = "ecommerce.com"
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "record" {
    zone_id  = "${data.aws_route53_zone.zone.zone_id}"
    type="A"
    name     = "www.ecommerce.com"
    ttl      = 300
    records  = ["${aws_eip.eip.public_ip}"]
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. The statement *"unable to deploy the correct resources"* is too open and doesn't describe what's actually happening.. You should update the question with (any) errors, output, expectation, etc.

Comment: Assuming you already have a `vpc` called `vpc` in your account then this looks okay. Therefore, I'm going to take a punt on this being because you don't have an AWS creds set up on the env when running. Have you set `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCES_KEY` for a user with adequate permissions to deploy resources into the account?